# How to convert an `int` array to an IP address string in C?

Tags: c

I have an `int` array which stores an IP address:

```
int ipArr[4] = {192,168,1,60}
```

I need to convert the address defined above, to a string like `"192.168.1.60"`. I tried the `sprintf` and `strcat` functions, but the code is still very cumbersome. And it is very tricky to deal with the period punctuation.
My code as following:

```
char srcIp[16];
int i=0,index=0;
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
   index+=sprintf(&srcIp[index],"%d",sourceIpInt[i]);
   if(i<3){
      index+=sprintf(&srcIp[index],"%c",'.');
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest a better way?

Comment: As you might know, a small piece of example code would be helpfull to see what you have tried already.

Comment: Please show the code and explain how it is cumbersome or tricky

Comment: On Unix systems, you may want to consider revising your code to use `inet_ntoa` and its relatives.  You'll need the input in a different format (packed into a 32-bit integer instead of an array of ints), but the standardized code may be more robust.

Comment: sprintf is the way to do it. Yes, the code will be cumbersome because dealing with strings in C is cumbersome. Get used to it.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I'd argue; When code is written properly, there will be no problem with understanding it.

Comment: @WilliamPursell yup, OP should use `unsigned` variant, or even better, `unsigned char`, he's just wasting memory

Comment: That's only a factor on very small embedded systems nowadays, but I share your pain fellow assembly coder :-p

Comment: The original was closed as off-topic, and most of answers use C++ idioms not avaliable when using C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simpler and easier to use a single `sprintf()` to format all of the ip address octets in a single call rather than in a loop as you are doing it.

If the buffer can be a local variable.

```c
char buffer[16];
const int ip[4] = {172,0,0,1};

sprintf(buffer, "%d.%d.%d.%d", *ip, ip[1], ip[2], ip[3]);
printf("IP address is: %s", buffer);
```

Or if you need to use dynamic memory you could do something like the following.

```c
char * buffer = malloc(16);
const int ip[4] = {172,0,0,1};

if(!buffer) {
    perror("malloc");
    exit(1);
}

sprintf(buffer, "%d.%d.%d.%d", *ip, ip[1], ip[2], ip[3]);
printf("IP address is: %s", buffer);

free(buffer);
```

In code above I've used dynamic memory allocation to create the buffer, and `sprintf` to write data to it.

Please note the `malloc(16)` - `sizeof(char)` is by definition equal to `1`, so we don't need to write `malloc(sizeof(char) * 16)`.

Comment: I wasn't the downvote, but it may be because of a few nit-picky things, like: more readable to do `malloc(16 * sizeof(char))`, using either pointer addressing or index in the `sprintf` (either all `*ip` or all `ip[n]`).

Comment: @anonmess `sizeof(char)` is by definition 1. And `*ip` is just shorter. `char` is one byte big; only thing that can change is amount of **bits** in char, denoted by `CHAR_BIT`. Array adressing is just syntatic sugar, from `a[n]` to `*(a+n)` so it makes really no difference.

Comment: I know that, just a good habit to be in, especially for someone new to C

Comment: If you know that, why did you insist it's for portability, not readabilty? Also, in many languages `char` is by definition one bit, I don't see a problem here.

Comment: Because it matters for some types, but I fixed it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But it's just logical that `sizeof(char) == 1`, so I thought I won't include it in my answer. Now, I'll include it anyway for new C programmers

Comment: @anonmess `sizeof(char)` is always 1 by definition, and should never appear anywhere in any code.

Comment: @user3386109 Yes, you're right. I share your view.

Comment: @user3386109 "Should never appear" and "may be omitted" are two different things. Like I said, it builds habit, especially for those new to C, and also can help with readability if the declaration and allocation are not together.

Comment: @user3386109: `sizeof(char)` is advantageous when code that previously used `char` is being changed to `wchar_t` or `int` or something else, because the person making the changes can search for places where `char` appears and decide whether they need to be changed. They cannot readily go searching for places where `1` appears, especially if even that has been removed since `malloc(16 * 1)` was written `malloc(16)`. The rule about not using “magic numbers” applies: You should not write `12` in code for a conversion from foo to bar. The fact that 1 is a fundamental number does not mean it is…

Comment: … not a “magic number” for `sizeof(char)`. Code should be written in part to express meaning to readers, and `sizeof(char)` expresses to readers that the programmer is allocating space for `char` objects. If the code just says `malloc(16)`, it is not apparently from that alone whether it is perhaps missing `* sizeof(int)`. But if it says `malloc(16 * sizeof(char))`, you can see the intent.

Comment: Okay, one question is left. Why would you like to use `wchar_t` for IP string? And why would you like to use `int` for string?

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk: (a) The purposes for which code is used changes from time to time. (b) user3386109 did not say not to use `sizeof(char)` just in this code, they said it “should never appear anywhere in any code.” That is bad advice.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Have you got a real life example why shall we store IP string in `int` or `float` array then?

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk: That is not relevant.

Comment: I'm just asking, there is no real usage of float or int data type here to store IP string, maybe I'm missing something out...?

Comment: Instead of `char * buffer = malloc(16);` or `char * buffer = malloc(16 * sizeof(char));`, you should really use `char * buffer = malloc(16*sizeof(*buffer));` That type of syntax is helpful regardless of the type of the pointer, and solves the possible error when you change the type of `buffer` but forget to change the type specified in the sizeof() operator.

Comment: for the RAM saving uC programmers (but having a lots of FLASH `#define NCHARS(i)   ((i) >= 100 ? 3 : ((i) >= 10 ? 2 : 1))` and `malloc(NCHARS(ip[0]) + NCHARS(ip[2]) + NCHARS(ip[2]) + NCHARS(ip[3]) + 4);`

Comment: I would recommend `calloc( 16, sizeof(char) );` myself. Makes it explicit that you’re allocating 16 `char` elements, and also guarantees what the initial values will be.

Comment: We just dont need the zero fill! It's adding useless overhead

Comment: It's simple question with simple answer, what are we even arguing about? It's certainly shortest, easiest and fastest in its class method

Answer (score -2):

A better way would be to use portable library functions!

It will:

- Make your code future proof by adding support for IPv6
- Make your code compatible with many other functions that use IP Addresses.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> 

void main(){
  // IP addresses might be longer on this system eg. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55958327/how-to-convert-an-int-array-to-an-ip-address-string-in-c
  char str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

  // this "socket address" is a very portable address format which you will use when dealing with sockets
  struct sockaddr_in sa;

  // this format is not portable or usable when dealing with other libaries, unless you convert it
  // note that technically 'unsigned char' is more accurate, but it will be processed slower than int on modern PC's
  unsigned char a_ipv4addr[4] = {192,168,1,60};

  // Don't do this! This will only work on little-endian machines, when compiled without certain optimizations - so it's not portable. That's why you should rather use the functions - some day soon you might want your code to run on a RISC V processor...
  memcpy(&sa.sin_addr.s_addr,&a_ipv4addr,4);
  inet_ntop(AF_INET, &sa.sin_addr, str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
  printf("Bad example with memcpy: %s\n", str); 

  // sprintf your address, and then convert it - if you absolutely have to use your format
  sprintf(str,"%i.%i.%i.%i",a_ipv4addr[0],a_ipv4addr[1],a_ipv4addr[2],a_ipv4addr[3]);
  inet_pton(AF_INET, str, &(sa.sin_addr)); // now you can use it in other functions
  inet_ntop(AF_INET, &sa.sin_addr, str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN); // just to show that it's correct
  printf("Better example from generated string: %s\n", str); 

  // you can also represent it as an unsigned int
  unsigned int ipv4addr=0x3c01a8c0; // c0.a8.01.3c = 192.168.1.60 backwards aka little-endian
  sa.sin_addr.s_addr=ipv4addr;
  inet_ntop(AF_INET, &sa.sin_addr, str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
  printf("Example from unsigned int: %s\n", str);

  // you can also represent it as an unsigned int, in decimal
  ipv4addr=192+(168<<8)+(1<<16)+(60<<24);
  sa.sin_addr.s_addr=ipv4addr;
  inet_ntop(AF_INET, &sa.sin_addr, str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
  printf("Example from unsigned int decimal example: %s\n", str);

  // Or just store it as a string to begin with...
  inet_pton(AF_INET, "9.9.9.9", &(sa.sin_addr));
  // or if you read it from another function, you can convert it back and print it
  inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(sa.sin_addr), str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
  printf("Example from string: %s\n", str); // prints "9.9.9.9"

}
```

If you're on Linux, try:

```
man inet_addr
```

To learn more!

Comment: Aren't they everywhere - isn't this it: https://github.com/hwoarang/uClibc/blob/master-metag/libc/inet/addr.c ?

Comment: Also, I didn't know about IP.ToString... that's great! But is it compatible with his array format?